# String in the small description - Luma Theme

Tags: luma-theme, magento-2.1.7

I noticed this string in the small description.
This "nessuno" string is seen only in Italian view while for other views it does not go out.
How can I remove it?
What is this string?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In backed edit that product select Italy store view and change short description .

Comment: Does nothing like this. The string always leaves

Comment: So that in not in Italian description? If possible then give reference link

Comment: http://www.avalonitalia.com/pouf-poltrona-sacco-piccola-bag-jive-tessuto-tecnico-antistrappo-imbottito-avalon.html